# Hide any URL contained in a given string except one

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-replace, url-validation

I have a booking site with a small chat system that allows potential guests to message hosts, for example to ask whether a room is available.

I want that any URL typed by users is hidden (= replaced by ****) except if it's a URL of my site domain.
I currently have a regular expression that successfully match any URL:

```
    $replacing_string = '****';

    $userMessage = preg_replace('{\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.it)\b}mi', $replacing_string, $userMessage);
```

I need to edit it so I can match all URLs except those containing *mydomain.com*

Expected results for these strings:

"Hi, check my site instead www.othersite.com/room/123"

after preg_replace:

"Hi, check my site instead ****"

---

"Hi, is this room available? www.mydomain.com/room/123"

after preg_replace:

"Hi, is this room available? www.mydomain.com/room/123"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Negative Lookahead**

We can do this with minimal changes to your existing regex:

```
$userMessage = preg_replace('(?!.*mydomain\.com){\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.it)\b}mi', $replacing_string, $userMessage);
```

The negative lookahead `(?!.*mydomain\.com)` asserts that what follows is not some chars then `mydomain.com`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Yes, but `http://example.com/ad_bj_whores/mydomain.com` ;-) I would suggest not to build the complicated XOR-like regexps, but do it in three iterations: 1. subst mydomain•com with some ★★★★★★★ UTF crap, 2. mask all the rest 3. turn mydomain•com back.

Comment: zx81 I think there is a small syntax error in your regex, but moving the opening curly brace to the beginning of the pattern, it works perfectly!


I also made a small modification to match also non-.com domains and to hide also the part of the url after the domain name:
{(?!.*mydomain)\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.it)([^\s]+)\b}mi


Thank you for the tip!


@mudasobwa yes, I considered that option but I was looking for a cleaner solution. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I noticed that the pattern I posted in the comment was not matching urls with no characters after the domain name, so www.othersite.com/room/123 was hidden but www.othersite.com was not.

Here is the correct pattern:
{(?!.*mydomain)\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.it)([^\s]*)\b}‌​mi